# Where do you call Context.SaveChanges if used in a service

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Im building a .Net WebApi and I abstract the logic away so I can use unit tests to test it. I use Entity Framework and the `DbContext` is injected by DI.

The flow of data is like follows:

```
[controller] -> [Service] -> [Controller]
```

To Unit test the Service I mock the DbContext and everything else and test the Service

```
[Test] -> [Service] -> [Test]
```

Nothing too excited so far.

Now, if for example I want to add a Point Of Interest then in the service I do something like this:

```
public class CreatePoiService{

   public void InsertPoi(PoiData data){
      DbContext.Pois.Add(data);
      DbContext.SaveChanges();
   } 

}
```

No problem with that. But now I have a Console application that imports 100000 Points of interests. And while this Console Application makes use of the same InsertPoi function, the `DbContext.SaveChanges()` is called after every insert, and this slows things down because its better to do after N inserts.

So Ive added a function to the Service class:

```
public class CreatePoiService{

   private bool SaveToContext = true;

   public void InsertPoi(PoiData data){
      DbContext.Pois.Add(data);
      if(SaveToContext) DbContext.SaveChanges();
   } 

}
```

Now I can call in the Console Application `CreatePoiService.SaveToContext = false` to not have EF execute the changes. And I can call the `SaveChanges` in the Console Application itself. Which works great. But still I doubt if there are better ways to do this?

Comment: If you ask me I don't think your service layer should be responsible for determining the scope of the transaction. Doing so will make you a lot more flexible for transactional work else you will need to create very specific methods in your service that come close to business logic. The layer containing the business logic should be the one that determines the scope e.g. by having a commit method.

Comment: You're actually touching on the broad issue of DBContext scope, but a general approach could be to make `InsertPoi` accept a list of `PoiData` and use `DbContext.Pois.AddRange`, which adds flexibility to your API at the small expense of making an insert of one item a little bit more complex.

Answer (score 0):

The normal pattern is that your services *will* call SaveChanges, but you can still scope a [transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions) across multiple service calls.

The transaction will control the durability of all the changes saved by the services because they all share a single DbContext instance as a Scoped dependency.